# A prompt for user input makes the app crashes

Tags: input, crash, prompt

I coded a demo for prompt user input, and it always crashes when i click the Ok button on the prompt dialog, giving me this error log:

```
08-24 06:24:11.669 3275-3275/com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-24 06:24:11.669 3275-3275/com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
08-24 06:24:19.019 3275-3275/com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-24 06:24:19.019 3275-3275/com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5c8d4160)
08-24 06:24:19.039 3275-3275/com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog, PID: 3275
                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                       at com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog.MainActivity$1$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5252)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am using a physical device running KitKat.

Here are the files:

**prompts.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvUserInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tv_message" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text">

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShowPrompt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_label"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
    package com.sano.tamer.prompuserinputdialog;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnShowPrompt;
    private EditText etResult;
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowPrompt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowPrompt);
         etResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etResult);

        btnShowPrompt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View vUserPrompt = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompts,null);
                AlertDialog.Builder adBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                // set prompts.xml to be the layout file of the alertdialog builder
                adBuilder.setView(vUserPrompt);

                final EditText etUserInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserInput);

                // setup a dialog window
                adBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                // get user input and set it to result
                                 etResult.setText(etUserInput.getText());
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create an alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = adBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java/Android NullPointerException on onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875100/java-android-nullpointerexception-on-onclick)

Comment: Sorry, i don't got the point. please explain with more details
Thank you

Comment: **i tried this, and it returns null:**  
`public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                // get user input and set it to result
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(etUserInput), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  
**and when changed the toast to this, it crashes:**  
`Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(etUserInput.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`  
any explainations?

Comment: Thank you guys, i found my mistake when i reviewed the demo example from which i made mine.
`final EditText etUserInput = (EditText) vUserPrompt.findViewById(R.id.etUserInput);`
i forgot to reference the AlertDialog view - vUserPrompt - to which the etUserInput EditText belongs.
Sorry for bothering you :)